# Mobile web "use our app" nag banner can't be dismissed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The latest changes to the Mobile Web code is making the "Read This Post In Our App!" Nag banner un-dismissable.  You cannot x it out. The grey banner only appears on questions, not on main page or asking a question or search.

On the other end, it's also not clickable, so it won't load the link to the play store copy of the Stack app. Double fault.

Using Chromium/Stock browser on Android 4.4 Samsung S4.

Comment: i've reproduced that and will take care about it. thanks for reporting!

Comment: Fix is already in repo waiting for build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. We've just fixed it and it should be live as well.

Comment: Confirmed fixed. Thanks.